# Creating sandbox through Salesforce CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to create a sandbox through Salesforce CLI. I am trying to create a Sandbox of developer edition but I am getting an error which I could not find anything about on Internet. We are based out of Europe

> (Error says something about locale en_US).

Command I am running:

```
sfdx force:org:create -t sandbox sandboxName=AESARPM licenseType=developer -u IberiaProd -a IntegrationRPA -w 30
```

Error I am receiving:

> Missing message org:SandboxProcessNotFoundById for locale en_US

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sandbox, Salesforce copies the metadata and optionally data from your production org to a sandbox org.

```
sfdx force:org:create --type sandbox --targetusername prodOrg --definitionfile config/dev-sandbox-def.json -a MyDevSandbox -s -w 30
```

The -s flag indicates that this sandbox is your default org for all CLI commands. If you’re working with several orgs and you don’t want this one to be the default, exclude this flag.

To directly define the required sandbox options, or to override the values defined in the sandbox definition file, specify key=value pairs on the command line.

```
sfdx force:org:create -t sandbox sandboxName=FullSbx licenseType=Full -u prodOrg -a MyFullSandbox -w 30
```

Here is [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_create_clone_sandboxes.htm) for your reference

Comment: I am sorry but that does not answer my question.I had referred to the same link to create the sandbox but if you actually read my query,I am receiving a weird  error.I am directly passing the key value pair in the command.

Answer (score 1):

Though the command got interrupted in VS Code with the error mentioned in the question, the sandbox was anyway created.I received an email after a while, that my sandbox is successfully created and when I checked in the org, I could confirm the creation of a sandbox.